# Loop to delete cells with specified text until text not found

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have about 50 columns and 200 rows.  Say about 100 cells contain the text "badtext".

The macro below finds "badtext" in the spreadsheet, notes the address, offsets to the left 1 cell, notes that address, and then deletes both cell addresses.  It only does this once and I need it to loop until it can no longer find the text "badtext" in the spreadsheet.

```
Sub macro1()
Dim StartRange As String
Dim EndRange As String
Cells.Find(What:="badtext").Select
StartRange = ActiveCell.Address
Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select
EndRange = ActiveCell.Address
ActiveSheet.Range(StartRange & ":" & EndRange).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

I was thinking a Do While, but I keep running into issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are deleting the cells with the *badtext* so you only need to keep looking for them until you cannot find anymore.

```
Sub remove_BadText()
    Dim str As String, fnd As Range

    str = "badtext"
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set fnd = .Cells.Find(what:=str, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                              LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False, _
                              SearchFormat:=False)
        Do While Not fnd Is Nothing
            fnd.Offset(0, Int(fnd.Column <> 1)).Resize(1, 2 + Int(fnd.Column = 1)).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            Set fnd = .Cells.FindNext
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

It wasn't clear whether column A could possibly contain the *badtext*. If it does, you do not want to try and offset one column to the right. In VBA, a **True** is the equivalent of **-1**.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is exactly what I needed.  And just fyi, Column A won't ever contain the "badtext".. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In general it would be nice to post your attempt of the loop-version, so we can have a look where the "issues" are ;-)
Based on your code (I didn't check if it does what you described, but you said it works..), a version with a loop would look like this:

```
Sub macro1()
    Dim StartRange As String
    Dim EndRange As String

    ' find first occurrence:
    Set cellHit = Cells.Find(What:="badtext").Select
    while Not cellHit Is Nothing Then ' as long as there is an occurrence left, run the loop body

    ' actual processing - as you did so far:
        StartRange = ActiveCell.Address
        Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select
        EndRange = ActiveCell.Address
        ActiveSheet.Range(StartRange & ":" & EndRange).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    ' find next hit:
        Set cellHit = Cells.FindNext(cellHit)
    wend
```

Instead you could also use a do while loop of course. You just would have to rearrange the find commands in this case.